# Magento: intercept all outgoing emails

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, paypal

I want to create a module that intercepts all outgoing emails and changes the subject.

Is this possible? Is there an event that is dispatched whenever a mail is sent?

If not, how can I override the order email / invoice email address at least?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

All the emails are sent via 'core/email_template' model, so you may override its method called `getTemplateSubject()` for such purpose. Unfortunately there are no events dispatched.

Comment: getTemplateSubject() is magic method. Actually, getProcessedTemplateSubject() method should be overridden because there is filtering here which can break changes made in overridden getTemplateSubject().

Comment: @Zyava but if you change getProcessedTemplateSubject() you may broke logic for subject template vars replacement. But if you are using getTempalateSubject() you can specify own variables for replacement as well. It doesn't matter is it magic or not, because Magento uses getter instead of calling getData('template_subject').